# Lightning I2C PicoBorg Reverse with Windows 10 IoT Rasbperry Pi 3

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, iot, i2c, windows-iot-core-10

I've been working with the PicoBorg Reverse motor board to control a DC motor. My application is written in C# and communicates with the board which is connected to a Raspberry Pi through I2C. The Raspberry Pi has DMAP enabled so I am using the Lightning provider by Microsoft.

The code for controlling the motor is:

```
private I2cDevice picoBorgRevDevice;  
I2cController controller = await I2cController.GetDefaultAsync();
picoBorgRevDevice = controller.GetDevice(new I2cConnectionSettings(0x44));
picoBorgRevDecive.Write(buffer)
```

Buffer contains two bytes, one with the command and one with the value. These commands can be found here (https://github.com/CodyErekson/picoborgrev/blob/master/lib/constants.js)

I am currently using WriteReadPartial but the byte I get back is empty, although the result is FullTransfer.

```
byte[] command = new byte[1] {I2cCommands.GET_A}; // GET_A is 5
byte[] data = new byte[3];
result = picoBorgRevDevice.WriteReadPartial(command, data);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the value of `result.BytesTransferred`? Have you set the `I2cBusSpeed`?

Comment: The value of result.BytesTransferred is 4. I did not set the I2cBusSpeed, where would I need to set that?

Comment: You can set the bus speed like this: `var settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(0x44);
            settings.BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.StandardMode;` Make sure the motor board and raspberry pi have the same I2C speed.

Comment: This fixed it, thanks :)